# Which Thread will a Service run in?

Tags: android, service

I have an Activity A that starts a service S via startService method.

 Now as per the documentation Service S will run on main thread or the UI thread

 Now my question is when activity A is destroyed will the UI thread still exist? 
 What will happen if I reopen the Activity A through its launcher icon will there be two UI threads spawned in total?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start an app by clicking on app's icon on launcher or home screen, Android will create a process for the app with a single thread (aka main or UI thread) of execution. This thread will exist even though there is no component started, such as `Activity, Service, BroadcastReceiver, ContentProvider`.

Then, it will find and start the default or entry activity for the app (which defined in `AndroidManifest.xml` file).

> I have an Activity A that starts a service S via startService method. 
>   Now as per the documentation Service S will run on main thread or the
>   UI thread  Now my question is when activity A is destroyed will the UI
>   thread still exist?

Yes, UI thread still exist.

> What will happen if I reopen the Activity A through its launcher icon
>   will there be two UI threads spawned in total?

When you finish Activity A, Android does not destroy the process for the application at that time. It will keep the application in the memory for faster loading if you start the app later.

So when you reopen the Activity A, if there is a process for that application exists already, then the Activity A is started within that process and uses the same thread of execution. Otherwise, Android will create a new process for the application.

> Which Thread will a Service run in?

By default, all components (including Service) of the same application run in the same process and thread (called the main or UI thread).

You can find more details in this link:

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads

Comment: So while the activity was killed can the service do network calls or database calls without the NetworkOnMainThreadException or any ANR on the thread?

Comment: @RahulRawat Prior Android version 3.0, you can do network calls or database calls on the main thread. From Android 3.0, if you do network calls on main thread, then you will get `NetworkOnMainThreadException` but it's heavily discouraged.

Comment: I am asking if I do that when there is no activity and only the service in the thread will then it happen too?

Comment: Remember main thread is still existent even though there is no components started. If there is no activity and only one service, then you can do network and database calls on main thread prior android 3.0. If your `minSdkVersion` is 3.0 or higher, you can do database calls on main thread (it's not recommended in Android). You can't do network calls because  `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Answer (score 1):

On Android platform: MainThread == UiThread == "ApplicationThread" (it doesn't really exists), so in your case the new Activity will NOT start a new Service but Service's OnStartCommand() method will be raised. The Service will continue to run in the "ApplicationThread".

Comment: So which thread will the Activity start in and will it create a new thread named UI thread. And while the activity was killed can the service do network calls or database calls without the NetworkOnMainThreadException or any ANR?

Comment: While one Activity or Service is currently running the "ApplicationThread" will not be killed, so any other new Activity or Service will start on that thread.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Android Developer Doc,

> A service runs in the main thread of its hosting process; the service does not create its own thread and does not run in a separate process unless you specify otherwise.